# Kubernetes Dashboard "is forbidden" all over the site

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

[image]

I get "is forbidden" all over the dashboard site in Kubernetes*(See image)

To reproduce:

1. Create a Google Kubernetes Cluster via the site, not from shell.
2. Select Kubernetes version 1.8.6
3. Open shell via the connect button: `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone us-central1-a --project awear-cloud`
4. `Kubectl proxy`
5. `echo http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui`
6. click the link from `echo`

Note: also tried: `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your cluster is RBAC enabled and the dashboard is missing a service account defined in the dashboard pod(s). You should be able to easily mitigate this issue by adding this SA and it's Roles/Bindings. Why is it not created in the first place is a mystery for me, unless you maybe specified something like ie. legacy auth.

Comment: A related reference to this answer: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Answer (score 4):

1 - Create a file **sa.yaml** and paste the contents below into it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

2 - Apply it - **kubectl apply -f sa.yaml**

3 - Create a file **rbac.yaml** and paste the contents below into it.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

4 - Apply it - **kubectl apply -f rbac.yaml**

5 - Now, **login** to your dashboard.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It would be great if you also explain what are you doing and why. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: A complete explanation of this can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md)